# PHP if statements being ignored

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm new to PHP and SQL. I'm trying to make a rule so that it will only show certain information for certain pages. The code I'm using is
include 'dbh-login.php';

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$i = 1;

while ($i != 100) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ui_off WHERE id='$i'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row['link'] = $id) {
      echo $row['title']."<br>";
    }
    $i++;
 }
```

The if statement seems to have no effect on weather the script echoes the title or not.

Comment: The `=` sign is assignment. Use comparison `==` or `===` instead.

Comment: Here is the manual page for [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not make any sense.

You are using a `while loop` and looping in it 100 times just to check if 1 row have the given id.

Why don't you search directly for the id? Your code will be cleaner and you will free some memory on the server by deducting 100 queries each time the page is opened.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ui_off WHERE id!='100' AND link='$id'" ;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row['link'] != '') {
  echo $row['title']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing == assignment. Here is the working code.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$i = 1;

while ($i != 100) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ui_off WHERE id='$i'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($row['link'] == $id) {
      echo $row['title']."<br>";
    }
    $i++;
 }
```